# How do you set and reset a bit in an unsigned long long integer?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I've been working on this for hours but I still can't get my methods to work no matter how many times I look over bitwise functions. (Switching it to just pos throws an error).

```
Bits() = default;

Bits(IType n) {

    bits = n;

}

void set(int pos) {

    (bits |= 1ULL << (pos-1));
}

void reset(int pos) {      // Resets (makes zero) the bit at position pos
    bits  &= ~(1ULL << (pos-1));
}
```

[This is what I get when I try to submit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD4oy.png) For some reason it seems to be filling out the bit with the entire long.

Comment: Is `pos` actually 1-up? Or can it be `0`? Also, what is `bits`? Looks like it's a templated type. Weird stuff can happen if it's signed...

Comment: http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: I find this is a perfect cheat sheet fot tricky bitwise ops.

Comment: @LIUQingyuan I don't see how the Bit hacks apply to OPs question. What he tries to do are most basic bit manipulations... [**How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/7478597)